# Merging functions and Abstraction (JavaScript) PLEASE HELPP

Tags: javascript, html, function

I'm an early beginner and desperately trying to make this code work. PLEASE HELP OR ADVISE ME. I'm trying to make the icon Hover (pop out and pop in) when mouse is on or off. :/

```
**HTML**

    <section id="ingredients"
    onmouseover="ingredientsHover('mouseover')" onmousedown="ingredientsNormal('mousedown')">
        <h2>ingredients  <i class="fa fa-coffee" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</h2>
    </section>
    <section id="preparation" onmouseover="preparationHover('mouseover')" onmousedown="preparationNormal('mousedown')">
      <a href="#" class="box">
        <h2>preparation  
        <i class="fa fa-list-alt" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</h2>

**JAVASCRIPT**

    function ingredientsHover(action) {
  if (action === 'mouseover') {
    document.getElementById('ingredients').firstElementChild.firstElementChild.style.fontSize = '300%';
  }
  else if (action === 'mousedown') {
    document.getElementById('ingredients').firstElementChild.firstElementChild.style.fontSize = '100%';
  }
}
}
function preparationHover(action) {
  if (action === 'mouseover') {
    document.getElementById('preparation').firstElementChild.firstElementChild.style.fontSize = '300%';
  }
  else if (action === 'mousedown') {
    document.getElementById('preparation').firstElementChild.firstElementChild.style.fontSize = '100%';
  }
}
```

Comment: your HTML tags aren't closed properly and it looks okay to call four functions in your case.

Comment: Thank you so much for your quick reply @Ramesh  <3
but its the html the problem its the JS. I need to know how to merge the 4 functions into 1 function instead...

Comment: Try something. It's a question of logic. You have four functions doing, as you point out, the same thing. Think through what is involved in abstracting them into a more generalised, single function? How will you make that font-size dynamic?

Answer (score 0):

You can pass an additional parameter when calling your function and then conditionally change your styles.

HTML:

```
<section id="ingredients" onmouseover="ingredientsHover(this,'mouseover')" onmousedown="ingredientsNormal(this,'mousedown')"></section>
```

JS:

```
function doSomething(element, action) {
  if(action === 'mouseover') {
     element.firstElementChild.firstElementChild.style.fontSize = '300%';
  } else if (action === 'mousedown') {
     element.firstElementChild.firstElementChild.style.fontSize = '100%';     
  }
}
```

Comment: THANK you so so much, you are literally my first ever online help <3 <3
I will try it now and post the feedback. I wish you a lovely day Ramesh.

Comment: do think I did it right ? I think its all over the place.
**HTML**
`<section id="ingredients"
    onmouseover="ingredientsHover('mouseover')" onmousedown="ingredientsNormal('mousedown')">
        <h2>ingredients  <i class="fa fa-coffee" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</h2>
    </section>
    <section id="preparation" onmouseover="preparationHover('mouseover')" onmousedown="preparationNormal('mousedown')">
      <a href="#" class="box">
        <h2>preparation  
        <i class="fa fa-list-alt" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</h2>`

Comment: The answer I posted is just one way of doing it. When I'm calling the function do note that I'm also passing the element itself. "do think I did it right" - well if everything is working fine then yeah you got it.

Answer (score 0):

reate an Array that contains different products, and get input from the user in which you
ask your user to give the position of that element he/she wants. Now remove that Item
from your array and console the removed item, Also display the remaining items in the
array and total number of items remaining.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).